# Electron app only runs in the background and doesn't show

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am trying to develop an Electron app in Windows 10 using boilerplate code like
https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge

After installing all the required modules and running the app in the dev mode using npm scripts, the electron app only runs in the background and doesn't appear.

This is a screenshot of the task manger which indicates that electron is running in the background:
[image: electron runs in the background]

but when I run the [electron quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) app, it works.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem so that I can use any boilerplate
to use frameworks like React or Vue

Comment: can you post a minimal example that doesn't run? And how are you running it: `npm run start`?

Comment: Thank you , I solved the problem in the github repo of electron 
I should listen to ready-to-show event 
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})